# Async DB calls to SQL Server from .NET Core intermittently slow

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, ado.net

I am noticing intermittently slow DB calls from .NET Core when I use async code. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and I can reproduce the problem with different versions of SQL Server. I can reproduce the problem using System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. Here is a typical function I use to access the database:

```
internal static async Task AddHeartbeatAsync(string connectionString, DataAccess.Objects.Heartbeat heartbeat)
        {
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO
                            [dbo].[Heartbeats]
                            ([ExecutingCommandId]
                          ,[StandardOutput]
                           ,[StandardError]
                           ,[InsertedDate])
                        OUTPUT
                            inserted.[HeartbeatId]
                        VALUES
                            (@executingCommandId
                            ,@standardOutput
                            ,@standardError
                            ,@insertedDate);";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("executingCommandId", heartbeat.ExecutingCommandId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("standardOutput", heartbeat.StandardOutput ?? String.Empty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("standardError", heartbeat.StandardError ?? String.Empty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("insertedDate", heartbeat.InsertedDate);

                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    await conn.OpenAsync();

                heartbeat.HeartbeatId = (long)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
            }
        }
```

I have seen similar functions take up to 10 seconds on a table that has a few rows. If I switch to sync code, I cannot reproduce the problem. I would like to continue to use async code all the way down to the database but need help to figure out how to fix this issue.

UPDATE: Database calls are originated from both BackgroundServices and Controllers. Both are async methods called by the ASP.NET Core Framework.

I have 5 instances of the same background service created like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, WorkerBackgroundService>();
}
```

The background service code looks like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!(await CommandRules.RunNextQueuedCommandAsync(...)))
            {
                //No jobs in the queue - snooze
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(_configSettings.CheckQueueFrequencyInSeconds * 1000, stoppingToken);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //logging
        }
    }
}
```

The controller code looks like this:

```
[Route("GetAll")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataAccess.Objects.SomeObject da in await _someRepository.GetAsync())
        {
            //Convert to Data transfer objects
        }

        return Ok(results);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _nlogger.Error(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without sharing sensitive info, what does your connectionstring look like?

Comment: @JohanP Connection string looks like this:
 Server=ProdDb;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=My Application;

Comment: Have you profiled SQL Server to see if the problem is in the database side?

Comment: In the database, SQL is executed quickly. Profiled it with Query Store.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any reason for the problem. How do you call the method? Did you profiled the execution, which of awaits is slow? Did you try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)`? Did you try Visual Studio CPU profiler to measure what part of the method is really slow?

Comment: Thank you @aepot. I did try .ConfigureAwait on all async methods in my data access layer - that did not help. I did not use a CPU profiler but I was able to determine that the slow methods are the ExecuteAsync and ExecuteScalarAsync on the Command class. Most of database calls originate from BackgroundServices but some from Controllers. Both are async entry points called by ASP.NET Core framework. I have 5 background services which are created like this:

for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
{
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, WorkerBackgroundService>();
}

Comment: @aepot I updated the original post with code from background services and controllers to show how async methods originate.

Comment: I'm confused with 5 Singleton instances :) btw, I have no ideas at the moment. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @aepot  I need certain operations to be done in parallel. So instead of creating 5 Thread objects would be sync code, I create 5 background services. These services pull data from a queue and do something. Singleton is just the way to create BackgroundServices.

Comment: Hi, could you check if you remove this line `heartbeat.HeartbeatId = (long)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());` helps? because in a multithreaded environment, mutating an object could cause a locking problem. so instead of mutating the object, it's better to return a `Task<long>` and update that line into `return (long)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync())`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment so I'm posting in answers.  The first thing that jumped out at me is you're using ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery which has additional overhead for no reason.

Comment: ExecuteScalar is required because SQL returns HeartbeatId. The data access object is then updated with this ID.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.net but are you pushing these through the threadpool? Is the delay confirmed in the SQL itself (on the execute) or is it possibly the service binding up?

Comment: Thanks @yugami  This is using the thread pool because the root calls into my code are coming from the framework into async methods. Then those methods call other methods that eventually call the database. I cannot reproduce the slow calls from SSMS (directly in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

could you check if you remove this line `heartbeat.HeartbeatId = (long)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());` helps? because in a multithreaded environment, mutating an object could cause a locking problem. So instead of mutating the object, it's better to return a `Task<long>` and update that line into `return (long)(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync())`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, removing this line did not help.

Comment: Did you update the heartbeat object somewhere after removing that line? Try not to update the heartbeat object anywhere. If you need you can create a new heartbeat object.

Answer (score 0):

This answer probably isn't relevant to the original poster given the age of the post, but figured I'd post an answer given my recent experience should anyone else come across this post. I too thought async database calls were the right path, especially given that my app was making many database calls as part of an OLTP system. Turns out that for short DB calls, synchronous calls far outperformed async, at least for our app. So unless you're making many long running (e.g. 1 second or longer) DB calls, go with sync and save the overhead of thread creation/destruction and context switching.

The OP looks like they were doing a simple insert. I'm not surprised that synchronous was faster.